# Laravel - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf - Cannot Open in Acrobat Reader via Chrome Extension

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome, dompdf, acrobat

I'm running into an issue with Laravel PDF Generation and the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Extension in Chrome. With this extension installed, whenever you view a PDF on Chrome, you get a little button that allows you to open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC:

[image]

For most PDFs, when you click this, it opens the PDF in the App with no issues. For PDFs generated in Laravel with the [`laravel-pdf` DOMPDF Wrapper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf), when you click the button, an error is generated:

[image]

There are no further debugging details, and Google searches are being less-than-useful due to the incredibly specific nature of the combination of the Chrome plugin and Laravel PDF generation.

For reference, this is the code to generate the PDF in Laravel:

```php
$data = $this->generatePdfData();
return PDF::loadView('test', $data)
->setOptions(['dpi' => 300,'orientation' => 'landscape'])
->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
->stream('test.pdf');
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Also, if there is no fix for this, that is fine; at best this saves one click (directly opening vs download and opening in Acrobat), but figured I would ask anyway.